# Alternative to mail or mutt in Linux to send mail?

Tags: linux, sendmail, centos6, mutt

I have a CentOS server which does not have the mail client. I do not have sudo access to install it or to install mutt.

What may be the best alternative that I can use to send myself an email to notify a failure/success of a process that I run on this server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could write a quick script in Python doing the job. Python is surely already installed, and you will be able to do the whole job with the standard library. Here is a small example as a starting point: https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
/bin/mail -s "Enter Subject Line here" -a /home/.../whateverFileYouWantAttached "you@YourEmailAddress" < /home/me/textBody.letter
```